# How can I find where does a method definition rather then declaration in idea IDE?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

In scala, class could combine with many trait and it's difficult to find a method definition.Does the function exist in idea?

Example:

```
trait A {
  def name: String

}

class AChildren extends A {
  def name = "AChildren"
}

class B(val a: A) {
}

object main extends  App {
  val bInstance = new B(new AChildren())
  bInstance.a.name
}
```

When you use `ctrl/cmd + B` on name of `bInstance.a.name`, idea will help you trace to `A.name`.Obviously, useful information is `AChildren.name`, it implements executable code. Could it can point to `AChildren.name`?

Answer (score 1):

In IntelliJ IDEA, move your cursor to the function call and press ctrl+b. This should open the function definition (unless you changed the hotkey ofc.)

Comment: thanks @irundaia, but It give me many choice,can I find the definition one in the inherit level？

Comment: I added a example on the question.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. This is likely due to the fact that class `B` only stores a reference to an instance of `A`. In the generic case, it could have been any implementation of the `A` trait.

Comment: thanks @irundaia,it maybe difficult to locate the implementation of `A` in a specify condition.